# Exercise 2.10.8 of Classical and Modern Numerical Analysis by Azmy S. Ackleh et al.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

First, thank you for reading my post!

I have been trying to solve the following problem(image attached below) and I have zero idea on how to approach this. I am self reading the book and was able to figure out the first 7 problems of this problem set. Can someone please give me an idea how to start this problem?

My approach:
We would want $|x_n-\alpha|<\epsilon,$ for arbitrary $\epsilon<0$ and large enough $n.$ This is equivalent to making $|g(x_n)-cf(x_n)-\alpha|<\epsilon.$ From here, I am clueless as how to proceed or how to use the given data.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Exercise 2.10.8]

Comment: $c=-1/f'(\alpha)$ fits Newton's Method very well. It also explains why they don't want $f'(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: I imagine that the book discusses fixed point iterations. They are also known as functional iterations. There will be a theorem stating sufficent conditions for convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root is $\alpha$. $x_n$ near $\alpha$, so $0<|x_n-\alpha|<\delta$

$\frac{|x_n+cf(x_n)-\alpha|}{|x_n-\alpha|}<1$. Condition for convergence.

$\frac{|x_n-\alpha+cf(x_n)-cf(\alpha)|}{|x_n-\alpha|}<1$ Adding zero to numerator.

$|x_n-\alpha+cf(x_n)-cf(\alpha)|<|x_n-\alpha|$

$|x_n-\alpha||1+c\frac{f(x_n)-f(\alpha)}{x_n-\alpha}|<|x_n-\alpha|$. Factor out $(x_n-\alpha)$

$|1+c \frac{f(x_n)-f(\alpha)}{x_n-\alpha}|<1$. Divided.

$-1<1+c\frac{f(x_n)-f(\alpha)}{x_n-\alpha}<1$. Re-expessed as a complex inequality.

$-2<c\frac{f(x_n)-f(\alpha)}{x_n-\alpha}<0$

$-2< cf'(\alpha)<0$ Condition on $c$ with derivative.

We don't know if $f'(\alpha)$ is positive or negative so:

$|c|<\frac{2}{|f'(\alpha)|}$.

Comment: thanks so much for this! I really appreciate it! I have a couple of things that I don’t understand. Could you please shed some light on these. 

1) what is the role of $\delta$ here?

2) I don’t understand the inequality $\frac{x_n+cf(x_n)-\alpha}{x_n-\alpha}<1.$ Isn’t the left hand side equal to 1 since $x_n+cf(x_n)=x_n$?
3) they say $x_0$ is close to $\alpha$ and you use the fact that $x_n$ is close to $\alpha$. Does $x_0$ being close to $\alpha$ mean  $x_n$ is close to $\alpha$?

Comment: Yep. The condition derived implies x_n+1 is closer than x_n. So if x_0 is close, so are all other x_n. Might have a proof by induction opportunity there.

Comment: $\delta$ is a bit extraneous, but is common to represent x values near each other whereas $\epsilon$ usually represents y values near each other. The fraction  is less than one. Equality only holds if x_n= $\alpha$

Comment: thanks so much!! This has been extremely helpful!